# Windows Security Alert when HTTP server is created in Node.js

Tags: windows, node.js

I am using node.js to create an HTTP server, it is working fine but at the first time when any node application runs, a windows security firewall interrupts my application.I want that this security alert should not shown , i had checked many references but did not found my answer.

Here is my code :

```
var http = require('http');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  console.log('%d request received', process.pid);
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello world!\n');
}).listen(PORT);

console.log('%d listening on %d', process.pid, PORT);
```

Comment: Here is my code :

var http = require('http');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000; 
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
console.log('%d request received', process.pid);
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello world!\n');
}).listen(PORT);
 
console.log('%d listening on %d', process.pid, PORT);

Comment: You can add the code to your question...

Answer (score 0):

Allow access to that application through the Windows Firewall:

> - Go to: **"Control Panel > System Ecurity > Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings"**.
> - Create new rule.
> - Select "Port" and press "Next".
> - Allow TCP and port your are attempting to expose (default 3000, you might want to expose 80), and press "Next".
> - Select "Allow the connection" and press "Next".
> - Check all: Domain, Private, Public and press "Next".

[Source](https://coderwall.com/p/mbov6w/running-nodejs-and-express-on-windows)

I would also suggest you replace:

```
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
```

With:

```
var PORT = 3000;
```

Comment: @AmitabhGhosh I +1'd your question, more experienced people may provide better answers.